# cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object, pipeline python

Tags: python, pipeline

I'm trying to work with this **Pipeline** and fit a Naive Bayes model for NLP but I got similar errors. The code:

```
nb = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(lowercase=Fals)),
               ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
               ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
              ])
nb.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

My x_train and y_train are arrays, example of **x_train**

```
array([[ 431,   79,   30, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [  19,   69,  133, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [ 360, 2338,   24, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       ...,
       [ 249, 2516,    8, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [1154,   26,   38, ...,    0,    0,    0],
       [  27,   25,   70, ...,    0,    0,    0]])
```

I got this **error**. I was looking for the documentaion but coudn't find anything helpful.

```
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough detail to be sure, but this error often happens when you read bytes from a file or the network, without decoding into a string first. Where do you get your data from? Did you check that the inputs are decoded into `str`? The `type` builtin function can be used to check.

Comment: On closer inspection, I think you're feeding numbers into `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer`, which actually expects text input.

Comment: The data is from kaggle about NLP, i have done padding and i got that array, now I want to create a model with NB. The array is about numbers, so I can't handle it with CountVectorizer?

Comment: You probably don't need it - I'm guessing that (or a similar preprocessing step) already has been completed. Check what the kaggle dataset/doc says that `x_train` in fact represents.